# Phonegap file compression and encryption zip

Tags: cordova, encryption, zip

Does Phonegap provide an API for file/data compression and encryption zip so that it can upload files securely?

Does HTTPS provides a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont thinks there is a compression library directly on PhoneGap, you should try to use the following compression libraries directly with JavaScript:

http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/

You could then get the BASE64 of the zipped file and send it to the server, depending on the contents of the file, you could encrypt the BASE64 string into something more exotic + SSL layer.